# Group By MONTH AND Quarter AND SUM previous 11 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I Have been struggling with this for about a day now :/. What I am trying to accomplish is return month values and previous 11 months int the quarter all in the same query.

So I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id INT,
    Date DATETIME2,
    Value DECIMAL(15,4)
)
```

I am trying to get data like :

```
          This Month   Previous_11_Months
January     100        1100
February    123        1123
March       211        2123
```

My Actual Sql :

```
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME2 = '6-30-2017',
    @plantId INT       = 1
DECLARE @endDateMinusYear DATETIME2 = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@endDate),
        @firstDayOfThisQuarter DATETIME2,
        @firstDayOfThisQuarterLastYear DATETIME2

SELECT @firstDayOfThisQuarter = DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ , 0, @endDate), 0)
SELECT @firstDayOfThisQuarterLastYear = DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ , 0, @endDateMinusYear), 0)


SELECT
    DATENAME(MONTH, PlantPollutions.Date) AS MONTH,
    SUM(PlantPollutions.BurnerNaturalGas + PlantPollutions.OilHeaterNaturalGas) AS THIS_MONTH,
    (
    SELECT
            SUM(SubPlantPollutions.BurnerNaturalGas + SubPlantPollutions.OilHeaterNaturalGas)
        FROM PlantPollutions AS SubPlantPollutions
        WHERE SubPlantPollutions.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, PlantPollutions.Date)
        GROUP BY SubPlantPollutions.Date
    ) AS PREVIOUS_11_MONTHS
FROM PlantPollutions

WHERE PlantPollutions.PlantId = @plantId
  AND PlantPollutions.Date >= @firstDayOfThisQuarter

GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, PlantPollutions.Date)
```

When I comment out in the sub query `WHERE SubPlantPollutions.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, PlantPollutions.Date) 
GROUP BY SubPlantPollutions.Date` it works

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data as well as desired results.  Do you have one row per day, per month, an arbitrary number of rows for each month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window functions are commonly used to get the previous or next row value such as with `lead()` and `lag()`, or to aggregate values for a `partition`, or rank rows with a specified `order by` (`row_number()`, `rank()`, `dense_rank()`). This takes advantage of a specific window frame of 12 rows (11 preceding rows and the current row) with this snippet: `sum(ThisMonth) over (order by Month rows 11 preceding)`.

Window functions work on the result set of a query, which is why the derived table to aggregate by month is used. Since you only want rows from a given quarter, nest the query again (by placing the first two in a [common table expression (cte)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)) so that the values from the rows you do not want are still included in the window frame when the `sum()` is calculated.

More on window functions, and specifically the window frame:
[Window Functions in SQL Server: Part 2-The Frame - Fabiano Amorim](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server-part-2-the-frame/)

Updated code for your updated question:

```
declare @EndDate datetime2(0) = '20170630';
;with cte as (
  select
      Month
    , ThisMonth
    , Previous_11_Months = sum(ThisMonth) over (order by Month rows 11 preceding)
  from (
    select 
        Month = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.Date), 0) -- truncate date to month
      , ThisMonth = sum(Value)
    from dbo.Test t
    where t.Date >= dateadd(year, -1, dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, @EndDate), 0))
    group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.Date), 0) -- truncate date to month
    ) s
 )
 select 
     MonthName = datename(Month,Month)
   , ThisMonth
   , Previous_11_Months
 from cte
 where month >= dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, @EndDate), 0)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OBVR79198

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------------+
| MonthName | ThisMonth | Previous_11_Months |
+-----------+-----------+--------------------+
| April     |       218 |               2291 |
| May       |       202 |               2312 |
| June      |       189 |               2357 |
| July      |       207 |               2335 |
+-----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

---

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use a window function to sum the current month and the preceding 11 months with a derived table/subquery/cte that sums `Value` by `Month` like so:

```
select
    Month = convert(char(7),Month,120)
  , ThisMonth
  , RollingSum = sum(ThisMonth) over (order by Month rows 11 preceding)
from (
  select 
      Month = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.Date), 0) -- truncate date to month
    , ThisMonth = sum(Value)
  from dbo.Test t
  group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, t.Date), 0) -- truncate date to month
  ) s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UTLDP89935

returns:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
|  Month  | ThisMonth | RollingSum |
+---------+-----------+------------+
| 2015-07 |       214 |        214 |
| 2015-08 |       195 |        409 |
| 2015-09 |       182 |        591 |
| 2015-10 |       168 |        759 |
| 2015-11 |       185 |        944 |
| 2015-12 |       152 |       1096 |
| 2016-01 |       165 |       1261 |
| 2016-02 |       186 |       1447 |
| 2016-03 |       212 |       1659 |
| 2016-04 |       232 |       1891 |
| 2016-05 |       193 |       2084 |
| 2016-06 |       168 |       2252 |
| 2016-07 |       174 |       2212 |
| 2016-08 |       213 |       2230 |
| 2016-09 |       195 |       2243 |
| 2016-10 |       217 |       2292 |
| 2016-11 |       200 |       2307 |
| 2016-12 |       200 |       2355 |
| 2017-01 |       225 |       2415 |
| 2017-02 |       202 |       2431 |
| 2017-03 |       192 |       2411 |
| 2017-04 |       175 |       2354 |
| 2017-05 |       220 |       2381 |
| 2017-06 |       186 |       2399 |
| 2017-07 |       205 |       2430 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: can you explain this a little bit?

Comment: @JamTay317 I have expanded the explanation, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never used a CTE I think that I am going to research them now.

Comment: @JamTay317 This is a good introduction to CTEs: [SQL Server CTE Basics - Robert Sheldon](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/).
The cte I used in this answer is a simple cte and is the same as using a subquery/derived table but I think it makes the query easier to read. The other type of cte is a recursive cte, which can be quite powerful when recursion is needed, e.g. traversing hierarchies (adjacency lists).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first two columns pretty easily:

```
select datename(month, date) as mon,
       sum(case when dateadd(year, 1, date) > getdate()
                then value else 0 
           end) as this_month
from test t
group by datename(month, date)
order by min(date);
```

Note:  The exact definition of "this month" may vary if you want everything to be based on the beginning of the month, but this is the idea.

For the third column, you can use `apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select datename(month, date) as mon,
       sum(value) as this_month,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from test t2
        where t2.value >= dateadd(month, -11, min(t.date))
       ) as prev_11_months
from test t
where date >= dateadd(year, 1, getdate() )
group by datename(month, date)
order by min(date);
```

Comment: I think GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, DATE) will mix data from same month in different years. I don't know whether this is desirable or not.

Comment: I am going to edit my question and post the actual Sql above I am getting an error now "column 'PlantPollutions.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."